# Arrays, functions, variables, and size() in Fortran 90

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90, fortran77

I'm very new to this language and have an assignment to convert some code from Fortran 77 to 90 and fix the code. I'm supposed to do the following:

1. Remove the implicit statement.
2. Convert array notation to fixed-shape [meaning IRAN(32) should be IRAN(:)]
3. Use the size() function to check the array size.

Any help on what to do here would be greatly appreciated. Based on the source code, I think I'm supposed to make a main program, then make subprogram makevec, which uses permutation function px(i); I'm not sure how to do this. Does this sound correct? What about the names of the variables? I looked up some of them (such as iran) and they seem to be related to random number generator modules (but again, I'm not sure of anything in this paragraph). I also found the modules "mod_kinds.F" and "ran_state.F" online but am not sure if they would help the purpose of this program.

I already removed the implicit statement in my program, declared some variables in the main program, and replaced the if loops with "select case (iran(i)." I also got rid of "return" and made everything lowercase.

Here is the source code :

```
SUBROUTINE MAKEVEC(NVAR,NOFIX,NRANFIX,IRAN,X,VALFIX,RANFIXEST,PX)
    IMPLICIT REAL*8(A-H,O-Z)
    DIMENSION IRAN(32),X(30),VALFIX(20),PX(32),RANFIXEST(20)
C THIS ROUTINE, CALLED BY MAIN, INPUTS NVAR, NOFIX, NRANFIX, IRAN,    
C X, VALFIX, AND RANFIXEST, AND RETURNS PX(I) = A COMBINATION OF THE
C VALUES IN X, VALFIX, AND RANFIXEST, IN THE PROPER ORDER (AS
C DETERMINED BY IRAN).
  NNNVAR = 0
  NNNFIX = 0
  NNNRANFIX = 0

  DO I = 1,NVAR+NOFIX+NRANFIX

   IF(IRAN(I) .EQ. 1) THEN
    NNNVAR = NNNVAR+1
    PX(I) = X(NNNVAR)
   ENDIF

   IF(IRAN(I) .EQ. 0) THEN
    NNNFIX = NNNFIX+1
    PX(I) = VALFIX(NNNFIX)
   ENDIF

   IF(IRAN(I) .EQ. 2) THEN
    NNNRANFIX = NNNRANFIX+1
    PX(I) = RANFIXEST(NNNRANFIX)
   ENDIF

  END DO
c write (,) "Initialized IG",NNNVAR,NNNFIX,NNNRANFIX
  RETURN
  END
```

This is what I have done so far (I know there is a lot of pseudocode and this won't compile):

```
program Initialized_IG
  implicit none

  interface
  subroutine makevec(var,nofix,nranfix,iran,x,valfix,&
             ranfixest,px)
  real, intent (in) :: nvar,nofix,nranfix,iran,x,valfix,&
                       ranfixest
  real, intent (out) :: px(i)

  REAL(kind=8) :: i
  real, dimension(32) :: iran, px
  real, dimension(30) :: x
  real, dimension(20) :: valfix, ranfixest

  integer :: i,nnnvar,nofix,nranfix,sum      
  sum = nvar + nofix + nranfix
  end interface

  nnnvar = 0
  nnnfix = 0
  nnnranfix = 0

    CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(i)
    call subroutine makevec

       select case (iran(i))

      case (1)
          nnnvar = nnnvar+1
          px(i) = x(nnnvar) 
      case (0)
          nnnfix = nnnfix+1
          px(i) = valfix(nnnfix)
      case (2)
          nnnranfix = nnnranfix+1
          px(i) = ranfixest(nnnranfix)
  end select

  write (*,*) "Initialized IG", nnnvar,nnnfix,nnnranfix        
  end program Initialized_IG
```

Comment: If it is standard conforming Fortran 77, then it is already standard conforming Fortran 90 code.  If your Fortran compiler is gfortran, compile it with -std=f95.  Fix any problems and hand the code in with a note that it conforms to Fortran 95 standard.  PS: google metcalf convert.f90.

Comment: I edited the question to reflect the things on which I'm confused. I use gfortran to compile, but I've been using -o program program.f90. What is the difference between what you are saying and what I'm doing?

Comment: It would help a lot if you could edit your post to include what you have done so far - it sounds to me as though you are very much on the right track, but let's se what you have done rather than just give you the answer.

Comment: There are many packages out there, that automatically convert F77 to F90 free-format. Do not do it manually if the codebase is large.

Comment: I agree with @evets that this is (mostly) already standard F90. The only bit that isn't is the use of `REAL*8`, which isn't standard F77 either. Simplest is to use DOUBLE PRECISION but, style-wise, REAL(KIND(0.0D0)) is better. Other than that, you're done. You might choose to convert to fixed-form but I wouldn't try changing the code as you'll likely introduce bugs.

Comment: I edited again to show some of what I have done. I don't want the answer, just some help figuring out what it is that I need to do to put the whole thing together. I declared the arrays with their dimensions but the instructions say they should be fixed-shape. I also am not sure whether the modules I mentioned would be useful (same goes for random_number(i)). I think I'm partly getting confused in the order in which the sections of the program should go.

Comment: @LeoC I am not sure if we both agree on what fixed shape is. In the standard term a(32) is explicit shape and a(:) is assued shape. If anything should be fixed shape, it would be the former for me. Also a change to assumed shape is not a necessary change when converting a code to Fortran 90.

Comment: OK, your making progress moving towards a more modern style which is what I understand you are being asked to do - it is true that all F&& is in F90 but that doesn't mean you want to use all parts of F77... But you firstly need to look at  subroutines, interfaces, and how arguments work (there are other issues such as kinds and loops, but let's start with that). Rightly or wrongly this is not supposed to be a discussion forum, so if you can distil your misunderstandings on that subject into a new question that would be good.